# Silverlight TreeMap Binding Text with Property of a list item

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a collection of MyObject in my ViewModel class named: `ListObjects = List<MyObject>`

Each MyObject object has a collection property: `List<MyInnerObject>`

Each MyInnerObject has a property: Name of type string.

Setting the data context to ListObjects works. I want to bind the `TextBlock's Text` property to:

```
ListObjects[0].MyInnerObjectList[0].Name <- ListObject collection's first item's MyInnerObjectList's first item's Name property.
```

How do I set the binding path property of the `<TextBlock>` to achieve it?

I have tried:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=ListObjects[0].MyInnerObjectList[0].Name"/>
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=ListObjects[0]/MyInnerObjectList[0]/Name"/>
```

It didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight allows you to [bind indexer](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/wpf---silverlight-quick-tip-inotifypropertychanged-for-indexer)

So, you first attempt should be worked. Write correct binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListObjects[0].MyInnerObjectList[0].Name}"/>
```

Sure, that there is ViewModel object in DataContext of TextBlock.

Good luck.